# How do I vertical center text inside a button element in 2022?

Tags: css, button, vertical-alignment

Check below, top and bottom space inside the button : bottom space is larger than top.
https://jsfiddle.net/FabienMorrow/6c78zsyj/3/

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="button.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="input-btn">SAVE INPUT</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
#input-btn {
  font-size: xx-large;
}
```

I want "SAVE INPUT" to be vertically centered inside my button.

I googled this for over an hour, with 10-20 years old solutions alongside nightmares/obscurs solutions based on lineheigh, vh, or even table, and playing with padding and border.

What is the less messy/outdated way to do this in 2022? I don't care about outdated or exotic browsers, for example flex and grid saved my sanity in element positioning, is there something similar to do this. Something simple and comprehensible?

---

I haven't supposed it's an optical illusion, let's get in this :

[image]

Honestly I've supposed the difference was bigger than that, hence it's not perfect.

As comments below suggested to me, should I suppose these minimal differences are font related?

Comment: I'm quite sure you are seeing an optical illusion because the top and bottom spacing are equal there. Otherwise you can fine tune the spacings using padding-bottom and padding-top and playing with line-height. But mostly your optical illusion may come from the font used or the specific word.

Comment: text inside button are by default centered vertically

Comment: The effect doesn't appear to show much in your given example, but with a different font-family that reserves more space for the underlengths of characters like `j` or `g`, it can easily give a result that appears not properly centered.

Comment: Thx all for yours enlightements :) I will deal with this minor difference

Comment: @CBroe ... that's related to the font baseline. But yet the layout properties behave correctly related to that.. of course if the font has a baseline highly shifted compared to the extension of some letters, it will provoke some further glitches in your eyes when judging if padding top and bottom are equal

Comment: The characters only look (more or less) vertically centered because they are all uppercase. Try putting something with a descender in like a lowercase y and you will see it 'unbalances' the vertical alignment. You'd need to know quite a lot about the particular typeface you were using and how it is rendered to get the uppercase characters pixel-perfect vertically aligned.

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned in comments, the slight difference is typo related, text is vertical aligned by default in a button

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).